# Unable to parse data in recycler view using Kotlin co-routines

Tags: android, json, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-mvvm

I am fetching data from the server and trying to parse it in recycler view using coroutines.Though  data has been fetched successfully but I am unable to parse particular key from my nested json.

Here is JSON response:

```
{
"status": "200",
"message": "Success",
"result": [
    {
        "_id": "60f516fa846e059e2f19c50c",
        "category": "Shirts",
        "sku": [
            {
                "name": "Oxford shirt",
                "brand": "John players",
                "price": "25",
                "color": "Blue",
                "img": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/koovs-1ff31.appspot.com/o/shi1.jpg?alt=media&token=64779194-e3b5-484f-a610-c9a20648b64c"
            },
            {
                "name": "Buttoned down",
                "brand": "Gap originals",
                "price": "45",
                "color": "Pink",
                "img": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/koovs-1ff31.appspot.com/o/shi2.jpg?alt=media&token=0b207b90-f1bc-4771-b877-809648e6bdc1"
            },
            {
                "name": "Collared",
                "brand": "Arrow",
                "price": "30",
                "color": "White",
                "img": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/koovs-1ff31.appspot.com/o/shi3.jpg?alt=media&token=2c1bb3f8-e739-4f09-acbc-aa11fed795e3"
            },
            {
                "name": "Printed",
                "brand": "John players",
                "price": "30",
                "color": "Olive green",
                "img": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/koovs-1ff31.appspot.com/o/shi4.jpg?alt=media&token=666f94bf-4769-44fe-a909-3c81ca9262f7"
            },
            {
                "name": "Hoodie",
                "brand": "Levis",
                "price": "44",
                "color": "Yellow",
                "img": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/koovs-1ff31.appspot.com/o/shi5.jpg?alt=media&token=65fccef4-a882-4278-b5df-f00eb2785bf1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "60f51c37846e059e2f19c50f",
        "category": "Shoes",
        "sku": [
            {
                "name": "Sneakers",
                "brand": "Puma",
                "price": "35",
                "color": "Black and white",
                "img": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/koovs-1ff31.appspot.com/o/sho1.jpg?alt=media&token=d078988d-9e85-4313-bb4a-c9d46e09f0b9"
            },
            {
                "name": "Running shoe",
                "brand": "Nike",
                "price": "99",
                "color": "Multicolor",
                "img": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/koovs-1ff31.appspot.com/o/sho2.jpg?alt=media&token=ed2e7387-3cf6-44df-9f7d-69843eb0bcdf"
            },
            {
                "name": "Yezzy",
                "brand": "Adidas",
                "price": "349",
                "color": "Gray",
                "img": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/koovs-1ff31.appspot.com/o/sho3.jpg?alt=media&token=2c37ef76-37bb-4bdd-b36c-dea32857291f"
            },
            {
                "name": "Sneakers",
                "brand": "Puma",
                "price": "79",
                "color": "Black",
                "img": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/koovs-1ff31.appspot.com/o/sho4.jpg?alt=media&token=4acd763e-8b93-47cd-ba45-92f34af4cf83"
            },
            {
                "name": "Joyride running",
                "brand": "Nike",
                "price": "80",
                "color": "White",
                "img": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/koovs-1ff31.appspot.com/o/sho5.jpg?alt=media&token=e3780dcc-52cb-49d5-9791-e0a44870716c"
            }
        ]
    
       }
    ]
}
```

I want to fetch **category**.

Below is data class

**Product.kt**

```
data class Product(
  val message: String,
  val result: List<Result>,
  val status: String
)
```

**Result.kt**

```
data class Result(
  val _id: String,
  val category: String,
  val sku: List<Sku>
)
```

**ApiService.kt**

```
interface ApiService {

  @GET("getProducts")
  suspend fun getCategories(): Response<Product>
}
```

**CategoriesViewModel.kt**

```
class CategoriesViewModel: ViewModel() {

private var categoryList: MutableLiveData<List<Result>> = MutableLiveData()

fun getAllCategory(): LiveData<List<Result>> {

    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

        val retrofit = RetrofitClient.getRetrofitClient().create(ApiService::class.java)
        val response = retrofit.getCategories()

        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            categoryList.postValue(response.body()!!.result)
        }
    }
    return categoryList
  }
}
```

**CategoryAdapter.kt**

```
class CategoryAdapter(private val context: Context,private val categories:List<Result>): RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder {
   return ViewHolder(ParentRowBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false))
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val model = categories[position]
    holder.binding.catTitle.text = model.category
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return categories.size
}

class ViewHolder(val binding:ParentRowBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
}
```

**HomeFragment.kt**

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

private var binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
private lateinit var adapter: CategoryAdapter

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)

    binding!!.parentRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true)
    binding!!.parentRecycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

    val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(CategoriesViewModel::class.java)

    viewModel.getAllCategory().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { t ->

        val len = t.size

        if(len > 0){

            for(i in 0 until len){
                Log.d("hell", t[i].category.toString())
            }
        }
    })

    return binding!!.root
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    binding = null
}
}
```

Here I have fetched categories somehow but I am not getting any idea  of how can I pass this to adapter so that I can show it inside recyclerview.

Comment: Can you do logcat for `response.body()!!.result`. Check if there is value or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HomeFragment you need to setAdapter to your RecyclerView

```
 binding!!.parentRecycler.adapter= CategoryAdapter(requireContext(),t)
```

full code of HomeFragment is shown below

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

private var binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
private lateinit var adapter: CategoryAdapter

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)

    binding!!.parentRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true)
    binding!!.parentRecycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

    val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(CategoriesViewModel::class.java)

    viewModel.getAllCategory().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { t ->

        val len = t.size

        if(len > 0){
            //add this line
            binding!!.parentRecycler.adapter= CategoryAdapter(requireContext(),t) 

            for(i in 0 until len){
                Log.d("hell", t[i].category.toString())
            }
        }
    })

    return binding!!.root
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    binding = null
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign an `Adapter` to the `RecyclerView` inside the `getAllCategory` observer as follows

```
viewModel.getAllCategory().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
    if(!it.isNullOrEmpty()){
        binding!!.parentRecycler.adapter = CategoryAdapter(requireContext(), it)
        // This will bind the Result list received to the recycler view
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the best way would be to inherit your adapter from `ListAdapter`. Because unlike `RecyclerView.Adapter` it has built-in support for submitting new lists.

This is more efficient, quick, and doesn't require creating new adapter object or completely updating all items in the RecyclerView. Because of `DiffUtil`, only the items that were actually changed will be updated.

So you `CategoryAdapter` should become:

```
class CategoryAdapter : ListAdapter<Result, CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder>(DIFF_CALLBACK) {

    companion object {
        val DIFF_CALLBACK = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Result>() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Inspection.Type, newItem: Inspection.Type) = oldItem._id == newItem._id
            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Inspection.Type, newItem: Inspection.Type) = oldItem == newItem
        }
    }

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder {
   return ViewHolder(ParentRowBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false))
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val model = getItem(position)
    holder.binding.catTitle.text = model.category
}

class ViewHolder(val binding:ParentRowBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
}
```

And in your onCreateView:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)

    binding!!.parentRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true)
    binding!!.parentRecycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    adapter = CategoryAdapter()
    binding!!.parentRecycler.adapter = adapter

    val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(CategoriesViewModel::class.java)

    viewModel.getAllCategory().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { categories ->
        adapter.submitList(categories)
    })

    return binding!!.root
}
```

Note that in your code above, you don't create your adapter instance at all and don't assign it to the recycler. So it wouldn't display anything at all.

In my example, I create an adapter in `onCreateView` and assign it to the recycler. In the Observer, we pass the data received from the ViewModel to the adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as @dhiraj-uchil mentioned, the problem here is not setting the missing adapter. I would also make `binding` lateinit or local. I would also extract `context`, and use it in other places too.

```
 val binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
 val context = requireContext()
 binding.parentRecycler.adapter= CategoryAdapter(context, t)
```

About making data class objects from JSON, I made a tool, that among others, generates such classes:

https://kt.academy/json

[image]